# Postgres is Throwing a False Foreign Key Constraint Violation?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key, postgresql-9.5, rails

I am trying to delete a LocalTax record from Postgres. Currently, I don't think there are any Employee records that reference the LocalTax in question (8).

```
=> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employees WHERE local_tax_id = 8;
 count 
 -------
 0
 (1 row)
```

However when I try to delete the LocalTax, I get the following foreign key error:

```
=> DELETE FROM "local_taxes" WHERE "local_taxes"."id" = 8;
 ERROR:  update or delete on table "local_taxes" violates foreign key 
 constraint "fk_rails_709dd4baab" on table "employees"
 DETAIL:  Key (id)=(8) is still referenced from table "employees".
```

Comment: Why are people downvoting without leaving a reason?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the definition (e.g. the `alter table`) of the foreign key `fk_rails_709dd4baab`

Comment: Aha! Well I feel dumb; there is a second fk from employees to local taxes by a different name! I can't believe how long I spent searching for that. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @a_horse_with_no_name I realized that my employees table had a second foreign key to the local_taxes table by a different name. The there were entries in employees.school_district_tax_id that corresponded to the local_taxes table that needed to be removed.

Comment: It wasn't only the different name. It was more important a different column that was referencing `local_taxes`.